Problem after upgrading from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS
I unfortunately updated my ubuntu server a few too early.
Now i have an error concerning base-passwd configuration and php-imagick also.
Debconf interaction failed  
dpkg: error processing package base-passwd (--configure)  
base-passwd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:  base-passwd

In  /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log  i found :
ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'base-passwd': 'le sous-processus paquet base-passwd script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1'    
DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() base-passwd: le sous-processus paquet base-passwd script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1    
ERROR Exception during pm.DoInstall()    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-xkfg4_3l/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 220, in run
    res = pm.do_install(self.writefd)  
apt_pkg.Error: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)    
ERROR SystemError from cache.commit(): installArchives() failed    
ERROR found exception: 'E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'

Is somehow this error known and how can i get rid of it ?
After reboot i have a fulll access to the server but over 700 packages are still waiting for upgrade.
I tried all this :
dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de php-imagick :
 php-imagick dépend de php8.3-imagick; cependant :
  Le paquet php8.3-imagick n'est pas installé.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet php-imagick (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Paramétrage de base-passwd (3.6.3build1) ...
Debconf interaction failed
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet base-passwd (--configure) :
 le sous-processus paquet base-passwd script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 php-imagick
 base-passwd

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
Atteint :1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Atteint :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Réception de :3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Atteint :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Réception de :5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 Packages [348 kB]
Réception de :6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main i386 Packages [172 kB]
Réception de :7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Packages [323 kB]
Réception de :8 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe i386 Packages [140 kB]
1 109 ko réceptionnés en 11s (96,5 ko/s)
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
700 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Vous pouvez lancer « apt --fix-broken install » pour corriger ces problèmes.
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 php-imagick : Dépend: php8.3-imagick mais il n'est pas installé
 php8.1-bcmath : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-bz2 : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-gd : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-gmp : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-imap : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-intl : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-ldap : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-mbstring : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-mysql : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-opcache : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-readline : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
 php8.1-xml : Dépend: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18) mais il n'est pas installable
E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt --fix-broken install » sans paquet
   (ou indiquez une solution).

apt --fix-broken install
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  fonts-liberation2 gdisk gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-snapd-1 gsfonts-x11 gtk2-engines haveged hplip-data
  libabsl20210324 libappstream4 libappstreamqt2 libatk1.0-data libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2
  libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libboost-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0 libbpf0 libcamel-1.2-63 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcolamd2 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libedataserver-1.2-26 libfam0
  libgcab-1.0-0 libgdata-common libgdata22 libglusterd0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgupnp-1.2-1 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgutenprint-common libgutenprint9 libhavege2
  libilmbase25 libixml10 libloudmouth1-0 liblua5.3-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmpdec3 libnautilus-extension1a
  libnetpbm10 libnetplan0 libnfs13 libnsl-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-pthread-dev libopenblas0 libopenexr25
  libopenh264-6 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libplacebo192
  libprocps8 libprotobuf-lite23 libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dbg libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal
  libpython3.10-stdlib libqt5multimedia5 libre2-9 libsane-hpaio libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsnapd-glib1
  libsnapd-qt1 libsuitesparseconfig5 libtirpc-dev libupnp13 libutf8proc2 libwmf0.2-7 libwnck-common libwnck22
  libxsimd-dev libzxingcore1 oathtool p7zip pass-extension-otp picom printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-beniget
  python3-gast python3-lib2to3 python3-ply python3-pythran python3-requests-toolbelt python3.10 python3.10-dbg
  python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal qpdfview-translations ttf-dejavu-core vlc-l10n
Veuillez utiliser « apt autoremove » pour les supprimer.
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés :
  libfftw3-double3 libmagickcore-6.q16-7-extra libmagickcore-6.q16-7t64 libmagickwand-6.q16-7t64 libraw23t64 php-bcmath
  php-bz2 php-gd php-gmp php-imap php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring php-mysql php-xml php8.3-bcmath php8.3-bz2 php8.3-gd
  php8.3-gmp php8.3-imagick php8.3-imap php8.3-intl php8.3-ldap php8.3-mbstring php8.3-mysql php8.3-xml
Paquets suggérés :
  libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev inkscape
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  imagemagick-common php8.1-bcmath php8.1-bz2 php8.1-gd php8.1-gmp php8.1-imap php8.1-intl php8.1-ldap php8.1-mbstring
  php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline php8.1-xml
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  libmagickcore-6.q16-7-extra libmagickcore-6.q16-7t64 libmagickwand-6.q16-7t64 libraw23t64 php8.3-bcmath php8.3-bz2
  php8.3-gd php8.3-gmp php8.3-imagick php8.3-imap php8.3-intl php8.3-ldap php8.3-mbstring php8.3-mysql php8.3-xml
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  libfftw3-double3 php-bcmath php-bz2 php-gd php-gmp php-imap php-intl php-ldap php-mbstring php-mysql php-xml
11 mis à jour, 15 nouvellement installés, 13 à enlever et 689 non mis à jour.
2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/4 617 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 10,6 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n]
Paramétrage de base-passwd (3.6.3build1) ...
Debconf interaction failed
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet base-passwd (--configure) :
 le sous-processus paquet base-passwd script post-installation installé a renvoyé un état de sortie d'erreur 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 base-passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
Broken coreutils:amd64 Casse on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
Broken python3:amd64 Est en conflit avec on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php-common:amd64 Casse on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mK >
Broken liblxqt1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99)
Broken php8.1-opcache:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-cli:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libfm-qt14:amd64 Casse on libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php8.1-readline:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99.0)
Broken libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 Casse on libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken php8.1-mbstring:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
Broken php8.1-fpm:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-cgi:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken mariadb-server:amd64 Est en conflit avec on virtual-mysql-server:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken mariadb-server:amd64 Casse on mariadb-server-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Est en conflit avec on virtual-mysql-client:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Casse on mariadb-client-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Casse on mariadb-client-core-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken systemd-resolved:i386 Dépend on libc6:i386 < none | 2.39-0ubuntu8.2 @un umH > (>= 2.34)
Broken mariadb-server-core:amd64 Est en conflit avec on virtual-mysql-server-core:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken mariadb-server-core:amd64 Casse on mariadb-server-core-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libkf5screen-data:amd64 Casse on libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.27.0~)
Broken libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken php8.1-igbinary:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Est en conflit avec on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii gK Ib >
Broken libboost1.83-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libboost1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken libwsman1t64:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un umH >
Broken php8.1-gd:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libtss2-tcti-mssim0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libnih1:amd64 Dépend on libc6:amd64 < 2.35-0ubuntu3.8 -> 2.39-0ubuntu8.2 @ii umU > (< 2.36)
Broken libtss2-tcti-swtpm0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Casse on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
Broken libmemcached11t64:amd64 Dépend on libhashkit2t64:amd64 < none | 1.1.4-1.1build3 @un umH > (>= 1.1.4)
Broken php8.1-xml:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libwsman-server1t64:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un umH >
Broken libtss2-tcti-device0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libtss2-sys1t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken php8.1-msgpack:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libtss2-tcti-cmd0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libkpmcore12:amd64 Casse on libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libguvcview-2.1-2t64:amd64 Casse on libguvcview-2.0-2:amd64 < 2.0.7-2-1 @ii mK >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un uH >
Broken php8.1-bz2:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-zip:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-curl:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libnih-dbus1:amd64 Dépend on libnih1:amd64 < 1.0.3-12build1 @ii mR > (= 1.0.3-12build1)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Dépend on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken php8.1-apcu:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgs9:amd64 Dépend on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
Broken php8.1-intl:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-redis:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-bcmath:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-fpm:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cgi:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-mysql:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 Dépend on gnustep-base-common:amd64 < 1.28.0-4build1 -> 1.29.0-7ubuntu4 @ii umU > (= 1.28.0-4build1)
Broken php8.1-memcached:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-ldap:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-imagick:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Dépend on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.16-1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
Broken libgnutlsxx28:amd64 Dépend on libgnutls30:amd64 < 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.5 @ii pmR > (= 3.7.3-4ubuntu1.5)
Broken libncurses5-dev:amd64 Dépend on libtinfo6:amd64 < 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 -> 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 6.3-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken php8.1-gmp:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Dépend on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
Broken php8.1-imap:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken ureadahead:amd64 Dépend on libnih1:amd64 < 1.0.3-12build1 @ii mR > (>= 1.0.0)
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken libfm-gtk4:amd64 Dépend on libfm4:amd64 < 1.3.2-1 @ii pmR > (= 1.3.2-1)
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken fwupd:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 2.3.1)
Broken php8.3-memcached:amd64 Dépend on libmemcached11:amd64 < 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu4 @ii pmR > (>= 1.1.4)
Broken php-memcached:amd64 Dépend on php8.3-memcached:amd64 < none | 3.2.0+2.2.0-4ubuntu3 @un uH >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken srvadmin-itunnelprovider:amd64 Dépend on openwsman:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @ii umR > (>= 2.2.3)
Broken srvadmin-all:amd64 Dépend on srvadmin-itunnelprovider:amd64 < 8.4.0-1 @ii mR > (>= 8.4.0)
Broken coreutils:amd64 Casse on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
Broken python3:amd64 Est en conflit avec on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ii mK Ib >
Broken php-common:amd64 Casse on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mK >
Broken liblxqt1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99)
Broken php8.1-opcache:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-cli:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libfm-qt14:amd64 Casse on libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99.0)
Broken php8.1-readline:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 Casse on libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken php8.1-mbstring:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-fpm:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
Broken php8.1-cgi:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cli:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Est en conflit avec on virtual-mysql-client:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Casse on mariadb-client-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Casse on mariadb-client-core-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken mariadb-client:amd64 Casse on mariadb-server-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 Casse on liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken mariadb-server-core:amd64 Est en conflit avec on virtual-mysql-server-core:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken mariadb-server-core:amd64 Casse on mariadb-server-core-10.6:amd64 < 1:10.6.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken systemd-resolved:i386 Dépend on libc6:i386 < none | 2.39-0ubuntu8.2 @un umH > (>= 2.34)
Broken libkf5screen-data:amd64 Casse on libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.27.0~)
Broken libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken php8.1-igbinary:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Est en conflit avec on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libwsman1t64:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un umH >
Broken php8.1-gd:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libboost1.83-dev:amd64 Est en conflit avec on libboost1.74-dev:amd64 < 1.74.0-14ubuntu3 -> 1.74.0+ds1-23.1ubuntu3 @ii umU >
Broken libtss2-tcti-mssim0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libtss2-tcti-swtpm0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Casse on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
Broken libmemcached11t64:amd64 Dépend on libhashkit2t64:amd64 < none | 1.1.4-1.1build3 @un umH > (>= 1.1.4)
Broken php8.1-xml:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libwsman-server1t64:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un umH >
Broken libtss2-tcti-device0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libtss2-sys1t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken php8.1-msgpack:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libtss2-tcti-cmd0t64:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 3.0.1)
Broken libkpmcore12:amd64 Casse on libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libguvcview-2.1-2t64:amd64 Casse on libguvcview-2.0-2:amd64 < 2.0.7-2-1 @ii mK >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1t64:amd64 < none | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @un uH >
Broken php8.1-zip:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-curl:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-bz2:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libncurses5-dev:amd64 Dépend on libtinfo6:amd64 < 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 -> 6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2 @ii umU > (= 6.3-2ubuntu0.1)
Broken libgs9:amd64 Dépend on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
Broken php8.1-intl:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-bcmath:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken php8.1-mysql:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on libapache2-mod-php8.1:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-fpm:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-cgi:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-apcu:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Dépend on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Dépend on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.16-1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
Broken libfm-gtk4:amd64 Dépend on libfm4:amd64 < 1.3.2-1 @ii pmR > (= 1.3.2-1)
Broken php8.1-ldap:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-imagick:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken php8.1-imap:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-gmp:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR > (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18)
Broken php8.1-redis:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Dépend on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
Broken php8.1-memcached:amd64 Dépend on php8.1-common:amd64 < 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 @ii mR >
Broken libgnustep-base1.28:amd64 Dépend on gnustep-base-common:amd64 < 1.28.0-4build1 -> 1.29.0-7ubuntu4 @ii umU > (= 1.28.0-4build1)
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken fwupd:amd64 Dépend on libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0t64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umH > (>= 2.3.1)
Broken php8.3-memcached:amd64 Dépend on libmemcached11:amd64 < 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu4 @ii pmR > (>= 1.1.4)
Broken php-memcached:amd64 Dépend on php8.3-memcached:amd64 < none | 3.2.0+2.2.0-4ubuntu3 @un uH >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken libwsman1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-client4:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii pmR >
Broken libwsman-server1:amd64 Dépend on libwsman1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken openwsman:amd64 Dépend on libwsman-server1:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 @ii mR >
Broken srvadmin-itunnelprovider:amd64 Dépend on openwsman:amd64 < 2.6.5-0ubuntu6 | 2.6.5-0ubuntu15 @ii umR > (>= 2.2.3)
Broken srvadmin-all:amd64 Dépend on srvadmin-itunnelprovider:amd64 < 8.4.0-1 @ii mR > (>= 8.4.0)

What could i try now to get a solution?
Many thanks for your help.
